# How to add more than one Paypal notes to my website?

Tags: forms, paypal

I need help with adding more than one Notes fields to my Paypal Donation form for my church.  Please see code below.  I don't believe the second Notes works.   How do I add more than one Notes field to my Paypal Donation form?

Also, is my Paypal donation form setup correctly? It works when I tried it but just want to double check.

Also how do I add validation on the fields? - I tried Required and it doesn't work.

Clarification:
Need more than one note field, The 2 note fields I have are:

- label id="MemberNumLabel" name="on0" - this works
- label id="Message" name="on1" - this is not working but I need more than one note field

Validation:
I want the text box to turn red if the amount enter is not a number and is empty.  I tried Required but that doesn't work

```
<td style="text-align: left;"><label id="DonateLabel" for="donatelabel"><strong>Donation Amount $:</strong></label></td>
<td><input name="amount" required="true" size="20" type="text" /></td>
```

Is my Paypal form accurate? Do I have the right url, host, links buttons, etc?

Full code below:

```
    <fieldset id="single" style="margin: 8px; border: 3px solid black; padding: 8px; border-radius: 4px;"><legend>Single Donation</legend><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr method=" target="_self"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_donations" /><input name="business" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" /><input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="Donate One Time" /><input name="tax" type="hidden" value="0" /><input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="2" /><input name="lc" type="hidden" value="US" /><input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" /><input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHosted" /><input name="button_subtype" type="hidden" value="products" /><input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="0" /><input name="cn" type="hidden" value="Add special instructions to the seller:" /><input name="return" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxx&amp;password=xxxx" /><input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxxxx&amp;password=xxxxx" />
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="45%" style="text-align: left;"><input name="on1" required="true" type="hidden" value="" /><label id="FundLabel" for="fundlabel"><strong>Choose Fund:</strong></label></td>
<td><select name="item_name">
<option value="General Offering">General Offering</option>
<option value="Tithe">Tithe</option>
<option value="Building Fund">Building Fund</option>
<option value="Church Anniversary">Church Anniversary</option>
<option value="Men's Day">Men's Day</option>
<option value="Women's Day">Women's Day</option>
<option value="Family Day">Family Day</option>
<option value="Youth Day">Youth Day</option>
<option value="Revival">Revival</option>
<option value="Homecoming">Homecoming</option>
<option value="Memorial/Honor Offering">Memorial/Honor Offering</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;"><label id="DonateLabel" for="donatelabel"><strong>Donation Amount $:</strong></label></td>
<td><input name="amount" required="true" size="20" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left;"><label id="MemberNumLabel" for="memberlabel" name="on0"><strong>Church Member #:</strong></label></td>
<td><input id="MemberNumField" name="os0" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label id="Message" name="on1" for="messagelabel"><strong>Message:</strong></label></td>
<td><textarea name="os1" cols="20" rows="5" maxlength="255"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input alt="Donate to!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" type="image" />
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="2" height="2" border="0" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form></fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more accurate? 
-What is the "note" field in your code?
-what do you mean with validation? Do you mean a radio button or something similar?

Comment: Peto I updated my initial post can you help?